# Need help with MySQL, joining two queries

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm running WordPress and I'd like to write a custom query that would show a monthly archive of posts based on one specific category. I used the debug mode to find out how to get a monthly archive based on all posts, select a specific category. Here are the queries:

Get montlhy archive:

```
SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS `year`, MONTH (post_date) AS `month`, 
  count(ID) as posts FROM wp_posts  
  WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' 
  GROUP BY YEAR(post_date), MONTH(post_date) ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

Select category:

```
SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
  AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy 
  IN ('category')  AND t.slug = 'blog' ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

I can't figure out how to join these two ;) Any help appreciated!

Thanks.

**Update:**

There's also another table involved called term_relationships, so that makes 4 tables in total. Here's an image of WordPress' database structure: http://codex.wordpress.org/images/8/83/WP_27_dbsERD.png

Anyways, here's where I'm at:

```
SELECT t.*, tt.*, YEAR(post_date) AS `year`, MONTH(post_date) AS `month`, 
    count(ID) as posts FROM wp_posts, wp_term_relationships AS tr, 
    wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id 
    WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category') AND t.slug = 'blog' 
    AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' 
    AND ID = tr.object_id AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id 
    GROUP BY YEAR(post_date), MONTH(post_date) ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

I know it's not the best way around, and that's why I need your help ;)

Thanks.

Comment: For those not running WordPress, can you post the result of `show create table` for each of the tables involved? In particular, do the two tables have a field that can be used to relate them to one another? (Or can they be related to each other via a third table?)

Comment: No one can't find the relationships between wp_posts and wp_terms from those queries alone, you better give us some table schemes here

Comment: vava, use http://codex.wordpress.org/File:WP_27_dbsERD.png full size http://codex.wordpress.org/images/8/83/WP_27_dbsERD.png 146 kb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this as the basis for the joins and where clause additions that you need:

```
    SELECT 
        YEAR(post_date) AS `year`, 
        MONTH (post_date) AS `month`, 
        count(ID) as posts  
    FROM wp_posts 
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wtr ON wp_posts.id = wtr.object_id
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON wtr.term_taxonomy_id = wtt.term_taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN wp_terms wt ON wtt.term_id = wt.term_id
    WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' 
    AND wtt.taxonomy = 'category'
    AND wt.name = 'enter category name here'
    GROUP BY YEAR(post_date), MONTH(post_date) ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

Comment: I fed it through wordpress filters and it worked, thanks so much Kris!

Comment: Great stuff :)  happy to help

Comment: @KrisC: Hey, can you give me some resource link where i can learn this kinds of complex database queries for wordpress?